# Xpath Add a 'custom string' on moving to other element

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have a question to find XML Elements using XPATH and JAVA wuth some constraints in it. 
Let me know if any more information is needed, or if this quesiton is been asked please provide the link which will help to read more.

Any pointers on what needs to be changed can be helpful

Below is the XML which i currently have.

From the below XML I want to only get text for `<Name>`, `<LocalAddress>`, and `<Zipcode>` for `<Name = 123 School>` and then create a HashMap where `<Name>` will be key, and values be Join of `<LocalAddress and ZipCode>`

As of now, I am able to get all the list of Name, LocalAddress and zipcode but not for a specific `<Name>` element.

```
<SchoolRoot>
<School>
    <Name>123 School</Name>
    <Address>
        <LocalAddress>
            <Street>This a fixed value ( In this example, lets say ) 123 St </Street>
            <AptNo>This is user input Value ( Can be anything )</AptNo>
        </LocalAddress>
        <LocalAddress>
            <Street>This a fixed value ( In this example, lets say ) 345 St </Street>
            <AptNo>This is user input Value ( Can be anything )</AptNo>
        </LocalAddress>
        <ZipCode>123</ZipCode>
    </Address>
</School>
<School>
    <Name>34564 School</Name>
    <Address>
        <LocalAddress>
            <Street>This a fixed value ( In this example, lets say ) 678 St </Street>
            <AptNo>This is user input Value ( Can be anything )</AptNo>
        </LocalAddress>
        <LocalAddress>
            <Street>This a fixed value ( In this example, lets say ) 91011 St </Street>
            <AptNo>This is user input Value ( Can be anything )</AptNo>
        </LocalAddress>
        <ZipCode>121314</ZipCode>
    </Address>
</School>
</SchoolRoot>
```

PLease chek the below code which i have tried

```
package com.gami.leetcode;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import java.io.StringReader;

public class xPathExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        //Build DOM


        String xml = "<SchoolRoot>\n" +
                "<School>\n" +
                "    <Name>123 School</Name>\n" +
                "    <Address>\n" +
                "        <LocalAddress>\n" +
                "            <Street>This a fixed value ( In this example, lets say ) 123 St </Street>\n" +
                "            <AptNo>This is user input Value ( Can be anything )</AptNo>\n" +
                "        </LocalAddress>\n" +
                "        <LocalAddress>\n" +
                "            <Street>This a fixed value ( In this example, lets say ) 345 St </Street>\n" +
                "            <AptNo>This is user input Value ( Can be anything )</AptNo>\n" +
                "        </LocalAddress>\n" +
                "        <ZipCode>123</ZipCode>\n" +
                "    </Address>\n" +
                "</School>\n" +
                "<School>\n" +
                "    <Name>456 School</Name>\n" +
                "    <Address>\n" +
                "        <LocalAddress>\n" +
                "            <Street>This a fixed value ( In this example, lets say ) 678 St </Street>\n" +
                "            <AptNo>This is user input Value ( Can be anything )</AptNo>\n" +
                "        </LocalAddress>\n" +
                "        <LocalAddress>\n" +
                "            <Street>This a fixed value ( In this example, lets say ) 91011 St </Street>\n" +
                "            <AptNo>This is user input Value ( Can be anything )</AptNo>\n" +
                "        </LocalAddress>\n" +
                "        <ZipCode>121314</ZipCode>\n" +
                "    </Address>\n" +
                "</School>\n" +
                "</SchoolRoot>";

        InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true); // never forget this!
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(source);

        XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//School/Name|//Address/LocalAddress/*");
        Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
           }
        }
}
```

Output is coming something like this :

```
123 School
This a fixed value ( In this example, lets say ) 123 St 
This is user input Value ( Can be anything )
This a fixed value ( In this example, lets say ) 345 St 
This is user input Value ( Can be anything )
456 School
This a fixed value ( In this example, lets say ) 678 St 
This is user input Value ( Can be anything )
This a fixed value ( In this example, lets say ) 91011 St 
This is user input Value ( Can be anything )
```

but expected output will have one school details at a time including zipcode. 
Something like this

```
123 School
This a fixed value ( In this example, lets say ) 123 St 
This is user input Value ( Can be anything )
This a fixed value ( In this example, lets say ) 345 St 
This is user input Value ( Can be anything ) and 'Zipcode' : <ZipCode>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit the resulting nodes by specifying an equality condition `[Name='123 School']` as follows:

`XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//School[Name='123 School']/Name|//School[Name='123 School']/Address/LocalAddress/*");`

This will result in your expected result (Tested using [this online IDE](https://www.compilejava.net/)):

`123 School
This a fixed value ( In this example, lets say ) 123 St 
This is user input Value ( Can be anything )
This a fixed value ( In this example, lets say ) 345 St 
This is user input Value ( Can be anything )`

Reply to comment: Did not find an `xpath` way of adding custom nodes to the returned nodelist. However, since you know what the structure of the nodelist output is - you can use the following in your output loop :

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
   if(i%5==0)
      System.out.println("Custom Message - your text");
   System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
   }
}
```

Refrences:

- https://howtodoinjava.com/xml/java-xpath-tutorial-example/

Comment: Hello Rann, thanks for the answer. It worked... need one more help! 
For the above outcome, which i was getting, it possible to add the line or some string, to distinguish ? as that would avoid having multiple expression list. Please look at below post for more detail ..

Comment: Hello Rann, is it possible to do that way ?

Comment: Hello, @Rann , nope those are dynamic elements... it all depends upon user input so i dont thinkl %5 logic would work

Comment: @HardikGami : Can you provide a dynamic example? I might be able to find a solution for you.